# In Foundry Contour, how can I analyze a prior version of a dataset?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I'm using Foundry Contour and need to view a prior version of a dataset at a certain point in its history.

How can this be done from within Contour?

Answer (score 1):

In a Contour analysis with the desired dataset as its input, click on the clock icon at the top of your path next to the dataset name. This will display available prior snapshots of the input dataset. Select your desired prior snapshot and you can then analyze that snapshot in Contour.